# SQL Server : ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN MAXDOP=1

Tags: sql-server, alter

I am trying to suppress parallelism in SQL Server while altering a table to add a column with the option `maxdop=1`. However I get an error in the syntax. I tried several ways but I can make it work, does anybody know how to use this option when adding a column?

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable] 
ADD neColumn varchar(max)
WITH (MAXDOP = 1);
```

[image: Print screen of the error]

Comment: Why do you want to? Btw, you can't, `MAXDOP` is not a valid option for the `ADD COLUMN` statement.

Comment: What makes you think adding a column is ever a parallel operation to begin with?

Comment: The table has more than 90 million records and more than 355 columns. Adding another column takes ages and one process that tries to alter the table to add the column has a time out exception.

One guy told me to suppress paralelism to improve the performance and proposed this solution but I could not make it work due to the syntax error. If you have any better ideas how to speed up the query that alters such table please let me know, I am out of ideas.

Comment: So why didn't you ask this and not a totally different thing? Make the database single user, kill all connections, add the column, restore multiuser.

Comment: ...and its `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)`

Comment: It would be nice to do so but the DB is a production DB, I cannot simply kill all connections and make it a single user.

Comment: @DeepanshuKalra only for `DROP CLUSTERED` and `REBUILD PARTITION` operations.

Comment: OPTION (MAXDOP 1) also gives a syntax error in this case but thanks.

Comment: Adding a `NULL` column of `VARCHAR(MAX)` without a `DEFAULT` takes that long??? You might think about a side table and bind this 1:1 or a `SPARSE` column. This depends on the data you want to store there...

Comment: @Shnugo: After 15 mins the query was not excecuted.

Comment: The "guy" who told you should back up his claims. I'm almost, but not entirely sure, that adding a column isn't a parallel operation. From SQL Server 2016 onwards (not RTM yet, unfortunately) you can specify `ONLINE = ON` to remove contention for long-running operations; before that, you'll have to schedule a maintenance window to make sure other processes aren't accessing the table. The `ALTER TABLE` can't proceed until it can take a table lock.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen. Unfortunately it is SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can't use query hint for an alter table.

See list at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx

Depending on what you want to do, you may want to set the server parallelism to 1 before you run your query and set it back to its initial value once you are done.

check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189094.aspx to do so.