# What will be best way to modify the column data type in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms-2014

I have a table which holds 64million records, I want to modify the `VARCHAR` types to `NVARCHAR` for some of the columns.

The normal alter statement is taking 5hrs to complete. which I can't run in production.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Sample] ALTER COLUMN [Name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL.
```

Any other method which will be faster than this.

No indexes, no constraints, no triggers, it a simple table holds 64million data.

Also, I can't do/create a dummy table with `NVARCHAR` types and load data to the dummy table, rename the actual table or delete it and rename the dummy table to the actual one.

Comment: The best way could be create an additional column and do data update incrementally. And alias the column

Comment: Could you please explain why you can't use a second table when you do the conversion? It might be important to know about the limitations you have when figuring out a way to do this.

Comment: You could add a new column, populate it from the old one, delete the old.

Comment: For completeness: your question isn't tagged with SQL Server 2016, but it's worth mentioning that SQL Server 2016 introduces `ONLINE = ON` for `ALTER COLUMN` operations. The operation would still take 5 hours (or even longer) but the table would remain available. Of course, whether or not upgrading is an option is another matter.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - my DBA's are not ok for that approach

Comment: @JeroenMostert yeah, but we are using 2012.

Comment: @Naveen: this question might conceivably be read by others in the future, and my comment is mostly directed to those readers. People might be using SQL Server 2016+ and not know online column operations are a thing now.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it faster to store the data in a temporary table, truncate and re-insert the data:

```
select *
into temp_sample
from sample;

truncate table sample;

alter table [dbo].[Sample] alter column [Name] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;

insert into sample
    select *
    from temp_sample;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this with sql-server but for an oracle db you can use a PARALLEL command 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> PARALLEL 32;
```

I think sql-server uses MAXDOP but I am not to sure how it fully works
[SQL Server : ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN MAXDOP=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023344/sql-server-alter-table-add-column-maxdop-1/37023616#37023616)

Comment: Certain `ALTER TABLE` operations do support parallelism and `MAXDOP`, but `ALTER COLUMN` isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. Add a new column with `NVARCHAR(255)` and update the column incrementally. This will not give any burden to the memory.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[YourTable] ADD [NewCol] NVARCHAR(255) NULL;
GO

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP (5000) [dbo].[YourTable]
    SET NewCol = OldCol
    WHERE NewCol IS NULL
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        BREAK
END
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[YourTable] DROP COLUMN [OldCol]
EXEC sp_rename '[dbo].[YourTable].NewCol','OldCol'
```